# declaring PHImageRequestOption variable in swift gives compiler error

Tags: ios, swift

[image]I am using the following code:

```
PHImageRequestOptions *options = [[PHImageRequestOptions alloc] init]
```

and it gives me following errors

> Consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';'

Comment: Seems you have pasted Objective-C code into your Swift method. That cannot be possible.

Comment: @OOPer can you suggest how to do it then in swift

Comment: you are right @OOPer. he is writing objective-c inside a swift method.

Comment: @SrishtiMittal can you publish your code here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code as you are using swift:

```
let options = PHImageRequestOptions()
```

Comment: if  you want to create a global instance then use
var optionRequest = PHImageRequestOptions()

Comment: var optionRequest = PHImageRequestOptions()

Comment: @Krishanvirsingh PHImageRequestOptions is a class. No need to declare it as var to change its properties.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure it's only in one line with trailing semicolon

```
NSInteger x = 0 ;
PHImageRequestOptions *options = [[PHImageRequestOptions alloc] init] ;
NSInteger y = 0 ;
```

//

in swift make it like this

```
let options = PHImageRequestOptions()
```

Comment: i had a habit of adding semicolons already. But in swift i think i can avoid adding trailing semicolons. 
Nonetheless, i have already tried adding semicolon at the end but doesn't work

Comment: can you structure the lines before and after it like what in answer , also you can edit the full code

Comment: your function declaration is in swift , and you create the object in objective c ?? , which language you need

Answer (score 1):

I usually do not answer to *convert my code to Swift for me* questions...

```
func exportGifAsset(_ asset: PHAsset) {
    let options = PHImageRequestOptions()
    options.isSynchronous = true
    options.isNetworkAccessAllowed = false
    options.deliveryMode = .highQualityFormat
    //...
}
```

You should better find a Swift code for your purpose. Nowadays you can find good Swift examples every here and there.

Answer (score 0):

THis code is for oBjective-c

First add property to  .h class

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) PHImageRequestOptions *requestOptions;
```

then add below line to your `ViewController`.

```
self.requestOptions = [[PHImageRequestOptions alloc] init];
```